# NSNetService on WiFi instead of bluetooth

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsnetservice

I have 2 iOS devices and an application which starts or connects to a NSNetService.

When both devices have have bluetooth turned on the data stream will automatically be done over the bluetooth interface.

I do not want that, i want both devices to communicate over the WiFi. Is there a way to force a NSNetService to communicate over the WiFi?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is there a particular reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is, I haven't looked into the docs, but I know a ton of games recommend disabling Bluetooth and ensuring WiFi is enabled for local multiplayer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Then i have to recommend my users the same.

Comment: I also have faced same issue, Whenever I turned Bluebooth Off it start working properly.