# iphone check WIFI  network switch is ON /Off 

Tags: ios4

It is possible to check  iPhone settings from an application? I just  want to check  whether the  WIFI network switch  is ON /Off . 
Please give me any suggestion if it possible or not.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This can not be done as far is I know.

I once posted a question like this:
[nsnetservice-on-wifi-instead-of-bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650452/nsnetservice-on-wifi-instead-of-bluetooth)

You can try to use the reachability project from Apple.
[Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)