# check if Wi-Fi switch is in ON or OFF state

Tags: ios, gps, settings, wifi

I'm not finding this simple thing:
I'd like to check if the user has wi-fi in active state or not, even if the device is not connected to internet.

So I'd like not to test the internet connectivity but only if the "settings" switch state ON/OFF).

This may influence a lot the GPS accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible (at least without any private APIs for jailbroken iPhone App development)

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119865/iphone-check-wifi-network-switch-is-on-off) link.

Hope this keeps you moving.

Answer (score 1):

I feel Reachability is the best thing to use for this scenario. Here's a [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_h.html)

Comment: @Anil I don't think that, this will give the status of *Whether WiFi switch is ON or OFF in settings?* The OP want's the status of the WiFi, not the network connectivity.

Comment: @Viral, it can't be done with public APIs. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119865/iphone-check-wifi-network-switch-is-on-off and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650452/nsnetservice-on-wifi-instead-of-bluetooth. As recommended in the second link though, you can recommend to your users (perhaps via an alert) that they enable WiFi while using your app.

Comment: @JRG-Developer That's what I've suggested in my answer.

Comment: @Viral, it sounds like we're on the same page then. :D